# How to set thousands data in SQLite?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set datas in SQLite. But datas is much and when begin to set in, app is freezing. I do not know what I have to do about it.

**My SQLite helper:**

```
public void UsersADD(String username, String picture_url, String owner) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE username='"+username+"'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(USERNAME, username);
        values.put(PICTURE, picture_url);
        values.put(OWNER, owner);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

The app is saving users followers and following list from twitter for track the profile.

If user have 6.000 or more followers and 6.000 ormore following, app is always freezing. I'm saving followers and following lists. how can I solve the freezing problem on the phone?

Comment: You can try not doing a `select *` and instead pull just the data you need, and also try querying in smaller batches. Are you actually creating a new connection for every single query?

Comment: I use just this code. I do not know what doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says, every time we work with a SQLite database we have to make reads and writes using an AsyncTask or an IntentService. Please, refer to this page for more details: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

This means that the method you pasted here might even be correct, but you have to call it using an AsyncTask, because when it runs on the UI Thread, it may take a lot of time, resulting in a UI freeze. Otherwise, running it in a separate thread, will keep the UI Thread free to run, and your UI will not freeze anymore

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried insert more than 5000 registers, so, you can count how many registers and if equal or more than 5000 broken in parts.

Comment: Yes I think also like that but then not all users will can use application.